# vscode terminal freezes after error with multithreading after running setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF 0

Tags: python, multithreading, visual-studio-code

I was getting the error "[warn 0] : terminating async callback" in python vscode when using multithreading with WebcamVideoStream, I runned the command setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF 0 and now when getting an error vscode does not exit, but the terminal freezes and doesn't let me write. How do I turn back from setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

type setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF "" on your command window and restart the computer